# JAXB can't handle Interfaces as parameter and return type

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb

Theres a work around to have jaxb handle interface classes by annotating your service Impl class with:
     @XmlSeeAlso ({SomeImplClass.java})

and annotating the interface file with:
     @XmlRootElement
     @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(AnyTypeAdapter.class)

however, this is a problem for me since the interface i'm using isn't editable and creating an Impl class for it is not doable since the interface has tons and tons of nested interfaces.

Is there a solution or workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you think from the JAXB perspective: It marshalls and unmarshalls the JAVA classes to XML, so there cant be any workaround to this.

As if I am **JAXB** and some one provided me an interface to marshall then I would have to **guess which concrete implementation** the user is referring to and it cannot do that. That's why I don't think it will be possible.